# difference between go away for/on

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Hello I am wondering when do we use "go away for" and when do we use "go away on". When we say, "I am going away for a business trip" why don't we say, "I am going away on business"?

Is there any rule to know when do we use "**on**" instead of "**for**"?

Comment: "Going away for a business" or "for business" don't mean  the same thing to my ears.  Which do you mean?

Comment: I don't know the difference between going away on and going away for

Comment: People do say "I am going away on business".

Answer (score 1):

Both of the following are correct:

- "I am going away for a business trip"
- "I am going away on business"

There are many different ways to word things which are all correct.

Comment: "On business" (and "on holiday/vacation") are fixed phrases describing the nature of time spent away from one's usual place. "For" in "for a business trip" indicates a purpose or occasion for going away.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with your statement that 'We say *I am going away for a business*'.

The usual expression is *go away on business* (for the purposes of one's work), or *go away on holiday/vacation* (for the purpose of pleasure).

We sometimes say *for* **a** *holiday*, but I've never heard *for a business.*

Comment: my question was about choosing the right preposition, is there any rule?

Comment: There is no rule; I was explaining to you what prepositions are _usually_ used.